# MySQL Query Problem - Joins and Grouping

Tags: php, mysql, join, doctrine

Im reposting this problem in a simpler fashion, as I was getting comments about it being too specific:

Based on the following travel model relationships, how do I select all **Itineraries** with at least one **Stop** in **Region** *X*, and still have the query return ALL the **Stops** for that **Itinerary**, even if the other **Stops** are in **Regions** other than *X*

I'm using Php and MySQL and Doctrine.

```
Region HAS MANY Country
Country HAS MANY Area
Area HAS MANY Property
Property HAS MANY Stop 
Itinerary HAS MANY Stop
```

Comment: Can you post your db struct, if it isn't gigantic?  Also, what information do you want to have from this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * from Itinerary where id in(
SELECT DISTINCT Itinerary.id
FROM Itinerary
LEFT JOIN Stop on Itinerary.something = Stop.something
LEFT JOIN Property ON Stop.something=Property.something
LEFT JOIN Area ON Area.something=Property.something
LEFT JOIN Country ON Country.something=Area.something
LEFT JOIN Region ON Region.something = Country.something
WHERE Region.something = X)
```

Comment: Why the left joins? Shouldn't those be `inner join`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  While this returns the correct Itineraries, it only returns the Stops in that Region, rather than all the Stops in that Itinerary

Comment: shouldn't matter, since the null right-hand side rows would be filtered by doing the where on the right-most table in the join sequence. but yeah, otherwise, it should be an inner join.

Comment: @dtj: can't have it both ways. but you can take this query and use it as a subquery to return the full itinerary: `select * from itenirary where id in (... other query here ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT i.*
     , sa.*
FROM Itinerary AS i
  JOIN Stop AS sa
    ON i.ItineraryId = sa.ItineraryId
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM Stop AS s
          JOIN Property AS p
            ON p.PropertyId = s.PropertyId
          JOIN Area AS a
            ON a.AreaId = p.AreaId
          JOIN Country AS c
            ON c.CountryId = a.CountryId 
          JOIN Region AS r
            ON r.RegionId  = c.RegionId
        WHERE s.ItineraryId = i.ItineraryId
          AND r.Name = @X
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from Itinerary where  EXISTS (select * from Itinerary where stop = X);

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, because the EXISTS returns true if there are any rows returned in the sub query. So what happens is, it returns EVERY Itinerary, if one of the Stops is in the correct Region, rather than returning only those Itineraries which have Stops in that Region

Comment: yup this is what is intended I guess as the question states "how do I select all Itineraries with at least one Stop in Region X, and still have the query return ALL the Stops for that Itinerary, even if the other Stops are in Regions other than X"

Comment: right...but the query above doesn't do that.  Your query is returning EVERY Itinerary, if one of the Stops is in the correct Region.  As the question states, it should return Itineraries that have at least 1 Stop in the Region, but still return ALL the Stops in the Itinerary.  Not all the Itineraries that exists in the DB

Comment: Ahhh now I got your point. But can't you put where condition in subquery to limit the records returned for EXISTS condition. something like ....EXISTS(select * from Itinerary where stop = X where property = something)